# Does Firestore's `get()` count as 1 document read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building user-to-user chat in my app, so I'm a little worried about the Firestore's pricing. I'm looking for the best way to structure my database, since I'm not sure if I can change it in the future. Does `get()` count as one read, or it will charge me for each message as a different read?

---

This is what I've done, I hope that it's the best way to do it:

```js
// Set the user's IDs
var userA = 1
var userB = 2

// Naming the conversation
var conversation = (userA < userB ? userA + '_' + userB : userB + '_' + userA)

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp()

// Initialize Firestore
var db = firebase.firestore()

// INSERT conversation name to the conversations list of each user
db.collection('users/' + userA + '/conversations').doc(conversation).set({})
db.collection('users/' + userB + '/conversations').doc(conversation).set({})

// SELECT conversations list for userA
db.collection('users/' + userA + '/conversations').get().then((response) => {
  response.forEach((document) => {
    console.log(document.id)
  })
})

// SELECT conversations list for userB
db.collection('users/' + userB + '/conversations').get().then((response) => {
  response.forEach((document) => {
    console.log(document.id)
  })
})

// INSERT message "Hello" from userA
db.collection('conversations/' + conversation + '/messages').add({
  time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()).seconds,
  user: userA,
  text: 'Hello'
})

// INSERT message "World" from userB
db.collection('conversations/' + conversation + '/messages').add({
  time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()).seconds,
  user: userB,
  text: 'World'
})

// SELECT messages from conversation
db.collection('conversations/' + conversation + '/messages').get().then((response) => {
  response.forEach((document) => {
    console.log(document.id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(document.data()))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `get()` on a collection reference or a query, it will cost one read for every document matched by that query.  When you call `get()` on a document reference, it will cost one read for that individual document.  The billing is all about number of documents read, not the number of times you call `get()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And one last question (if that's the case) - is there a way to limit the `get()` to let's say 10 documents? And then call for another 10 documents with another call (load more button)? And the sort to be by `time`?

Comment: Please read the documentation about that.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: Ha, so cool! Just like MySQL, even simpler. Doug, thank you for your help, I'll finish my app now. Everything is ready, except the chat, lol. I wish you a great day! :-)